# Rename grandchild folders after their grandparents

Tags: rename

I have the following folder structure on a NAS running linux

> Grandparent1
>
> > Parent
> >
> > > > Grandchild
>
> Grandparent2
>
> > Parent
> >
> > > > Grandchild
>
> Grandparent3
>
> > Parent
> >
> > > > Grandchild
>
> Grandparentn
>
> > Parent
> >
> > > > Grandchild

I want to rename all **Grandchild** folders with their respective **Parent**, so it will end up like this:

> Grandparent1
>
> > Parent
> >
> > > > Grandparent1
>
> Grandparent2
>
> > Parent
> >
> > > > Grandparent2
>
> Grandparent3
>
> > Parent
> >
> > > > Grandparent3
>
> Grandparentn
>
> > Parent
> >
> > > > Grandparentn

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can write shell script do to that.

```
for i in {1..n}
do
 mv Grandparent${i}/Parent/Grandchild Grandparent${i}/Parent/Grandparent${i}
done
```

Comment: I should have mentioned the folders' names do not follow a naming convention. Grandparent, Parent and Grandchild were the names I used just to explain the folder structure I have.